# Book that involves sentient nanotechnology integrating itself as a "digital assistant" in nine people

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens, nanotechnology

I can't quite place the name of this book. I thought it was *The Gift*, but I was wrong. The book was in English and I don't remember the year. I feel like saying more recently, circa 2017?

Basically what I remember is that the main character somehow ended up taking home. The extraterrestrial orb (sitting on a table in his house) when touched would talk to him. It informed him that it meant no harm and would integrate in his body as an assistant without the ability to refuse his wishes, penalty being "death".

I seem to also remember that there were nine people afflicted with these orbs by the end of the book. They were in a competition against authorities (maybe just one antagonist) using the same technology against them. It was also revealed that a similar number of orbs were also delivered to other countries, and that a war against the race that destroyed the orb's creators was about to begin and that humans ought to prepare.

They were also trying to set up some kind of futuristic global network to prepare for communication capacity between the people using the alien technology.

The orb, when integrated into the person's body, could augment the body or create nanobots (or the like) from surrounding materials. I remember these nanobots being used to tear down a house, create a tunnel underground with a floor smooth and slippery like ice and dismantle a police drone mid-flight.

I remember that the antagonist was killed by abusing the body-augmentation abilities afforded by the technology, and then asked that his "digital assistant" kill itself,causing his body to fail without the support of the alien technology.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! great start. could you try to add two more things (if possible)? 1. The language you read it in and, 2. Approximate year (say the early 90s etc.). Will make it more easier to help you